# Does Hyperldeger Fabric use REST APIs?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I saw a lot of references to grpc and client interactions with http2 to the endorser. I have also seen some references to rest api. My confusion is that with so many versions now from 0.6 to 2.2 I am getting confused on the actual protocol standard from the client to the endorser.

If I have 2.0, is everything using grpc which implements the api from the client to the endorser via http2 and the sdk?

Answer (score 2):

There are four primary APIs used for interactions between the Fabric SDK Client and the Fabric peers and orderers.  These services are all gRPC based.

The peer exposes a `Propose` rpc, a `Discover` rpc and a `Deliver` rpc.  The `Propose` rpc is responsible for producing endorsements which are bundled by the client into a transaction.  The `Discover` rpc is used to help a client understand which peers a proposal could and or should be endorsed by.  The `Deliver` rpc is used by the client to consume blocks as they are committed and detect transaction commitment.

The orderer exposes a `Broadcast` and `Deliver` rpc.  The `Broadcast` rpc accepts transactions to be included into the blockchain, and the `Deliver` rpc provides blocks (usually to peers, but sometimes to clients as well).

There are some other components in the system which provide other APIs -- the operations endpoints meant for health checks and metrics, for instance use REST.  But, these components are typically not consumed by a client application.

Comment: That is very useful. By rpc you mean grpc?

Comment: Yes, these are all gRPC rpcs.